# handle multiple checkboxes and complex data structure (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Since I am pretty new to React and also not a huge expert on JS especially ES6, I wonder how to make my code (that works) prettier and refactor it.

I want to handle multiple checkboxes in a form and store the current value in the state object. Since the checkboxes are grouped I want a structure as answeredTasks like that:

```
{  
   "isLoaded":true,
   "answeredTasks":{  
      "1":[  
         "green",
         "blue",
         "red"
      ],
      "5":[  
         "car",
         "cat",
         "house"
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is my onChange method on a checkbox:

```
  checkBoxOnChange = e => {
    let currentAnswers = this.state.answeredTasks;

    let element = e.currentTarget;

    // if it is the first answer checked
    if (currentAnswers[element.name] === undefined) {
      currentAnswers[element.name] = [];
    }

    // if uncheck
    if (!element.checked) {
      const index = currentAnswers[element.name].indexOf(element.value);
      currentAnswers[element.name].splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      currentAnswers[element.name].push(element.value);
    }

    this.setState({ answeredTasks: currentAnswers });
  };
```

Can you tell me how to improve my method, especially with ES6?
I mostly struggled with creating the data structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the code to your whole component code?
Also, as an advice, avoid using "let" in your code and instead use "const" to avoid mutating data. Try learning functional programming paradigm which is the best industry practice.

Answer (score 0):

I preferred I could see your whole code.
But if I wanted to suggest you any change:

1. In general, avoid using "let" in your code and instead use "const". This way, you avoid mutating data which is the industry best practice, and React documentation highly recommends that.
2. Avoid using splice/push/pop methods which mutate data, and instead use array functions such as filter/map/some/every etc... The methods I mentioned do not mutate data and instead return a referencially different object.

Here is the change you should make:

```
checkBoxOnChange = e => {
    const currentAnswers = this.state.answeredTasks;
    const element = e.target;

    const newAnswers = !element.checked ?
        (currentAnswers[element.name] || []).filter(val => val !== element.value) :
        (currentAnswers[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);  

    this.setState({ answeredTasks: {...currentAnswers, newAnswers} });
 };
```

Please note that the {...currentAnswers, newAnswers} inside setState() function is merging the currentAnswers with the new changes in newAnswers. i.e. newAnswers will overwrite the specific object in the outer array.
This is the Functional way of doing things.

Comment: "let" and instead use "const" - it is not important in the case of objects. When you're "mutating" an array or object you're not re-assigning or re-declaring the constant, it's already declared and assigned, you're just adding to the "list" that the constant points to.

Comment: Victor, you are a bit confused. Mutation is NOT re-declaring a new object, and that is exactly why it is bad !! ... Functional programming doesn't like side effects, and doesn't like making the changes to the referentially same object.
Immutability means you should referencially create a new object with every new change, which is the industry best practice and ReactJs is highly recommending it.

Comment: Modifying the object/array with methods like splice/pop/push are mutating the object (changing the same object), where as using map/filter/some/every are NOT. They will referentially return a new object/array which is the "pure" way of doing things, and thus recommended by ReactJs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the first but here is my version with a test

```
static changeAnswers = ({target: {name, value, checked}}) => 
  checked
    ? { ...answeredTasks, ...{ [name]: [...(answeredTasks[name] || []), value] } }
    : {
        ...answeredTasks,
        ...{ [name]: (answeredTasks[name] || []).filter(e => e !== value) }
      }

checkBoxOnChange = e => {
  const {answeredTasks} = this.state
  this.setState({answeredTasks: myComponent.changeAnswers(e)})
}
```

```js
const answeredTasks = { "1": ["green", "blue", "red"] }

const elements = [
  { name: "1", value: "green", checked: false },
  { name: "1", value: "black", checked: true },
  { name: "2", value: "lol", checked: true },
  { name: "2", value: "lol", checked: false }
]

const click = ({ name, value, checked }) =>
  checked
    ? { ...answeredTasks, ...{ [name]: [...(answeredTasks[name] || []), value] } }
    : {
        ...answeredTasks,
        ...{ [name]: (answeredTasks[name] || []).filter(e => e !== value) }
      }

elements.map(element => console.log(click(element)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mutation methods `splice` and `push`. Use destructuring

```
const checkBoxOnChange = (ev) => {
  const currentAnswers = this.state.answeredTasks;
  const { name, value, checked } = ev.currentTarget;

  if (!currentAnswers[name]) {
    currentAnswers[name] = [];
  }

  currentAnswers[name] = checked
    ? currentAnswers[name].concat(value)
    : currentAnswers[name].filter((item) => item !== value);

  this.setState({ answeredTasks: currentAnswers });
};
```